# How to display parent div over child div

Tags: html, css

If I have this:

```
<div id='parent'>
<p>Parent stuff here</p>

  <div id='child'>Child stuff here</div>

</div>
```

Is there a way to make the parent div appear overtop of the child div without using `position:absolute`?  Basically, you wouldn't see the child div at all.  `z-index` doesn't seem to work.  I want to do this with a transparent PNG so that I can highlight certain divs on mouseover - the transparentness will allow the under stuff to still be seen a little.

Thanks!

Comment: Why not do it the other way around? Put the child div on top of the parent, put it at 0 opacity by default, and then `onhover` increase its opacity. Has the exact same effect without making it more complicated on your part.

Comment: I agree with @Purmou, that is a much easier way.

Comment: "z-index doesn't seem to work" - as far as I know z-index works only when you have position property to the divs. but as long as you don't want the position:absolute I am not sure you'll get that div on top only with css. may be js, but I don't know

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`z-index` will only work if a position other than `static` (the default) is set on that element. Add `position: relative;` to the relevant element and `z-index` will work. Here is an example: http://jsfiddle.net/sl1dr/8gR6V/

Comment: Thanks!  I figured this out just after... this isn't exactly what I wanted, but I'll ask another question.