# Font awsome icon not coming on top of Materialize css progress/determinate

Tags: css, font-awesome, materialize

I'm trying to show a fontawsome icon to come on top of a materialize css progress/determinate div. But with no luck. the icon shows but not completely part of it is clipped/hidden. I have tried a lot of solution but no help.

```css
.progress .determinate {
  overflow: visible;
  z-index: 1;
}
.progress .determinate .fa {
  position: absolute;
  top: -5px;
  font-size: 12px;
  right: 0px;
  visibility: visible;
  z-index: 9;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.97.8/css/materialize.min.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.97.8/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.css"></script>

<div class="col l9 m9 s9 ">
  <div class="col l12 m12 s12">
    <div class="progress">
      <div class="determinate" style="width:70%">
        <i class="fa fa-circle"></i>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Below is the image showing what it should look like. But i m not able to figure out how to achieve this even after hours of struggling. In the image the circle is the `fa-circle` icon

[image: In the image the circle is the <code>fa-circle</code> icon]

Below are some of the posts i have tried

1. [First](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1174874/show-child-element-above-parent-element-using-css)
2. [Second](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8236488/how-to-display-parent-div-over-child-div)
3. [Third](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19681154/get-a-child-div-to-appear-above-absolutely-positioned-parent)

Tried several other things but could make it work. Any help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your .progress overflow is hidden, so make it visible

```
.progress {

     overflow: visible;

     }
```

Answer (score 2):

### Here is the solution

http://codepen.io/Bhupinderkumar/pen/dOLOPJ check here i created with codepen and got the solution or you just need to add this

```
.progress{ overflow:inherit!important }
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `.progress` `overflow` is `hidden`, so make it visible by adding code as below,

```
.progress{
  overflow:visible !important;
}
```

**!important** - by adding `!important` to your CSS overflow property, you are telling to unseen other important rules and apply this first.

```css
.progress{
  overflow:visible !important;
}
.progress .determinate {
  width:70%;
}
.progress .determinate .fa {
  position:absolute;
  top:-5px;
  right:0;
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.97.8/css/materialize.min.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.97.8/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.css">

<div class="col l9 m9 s9 ">
  <div class="col l12 m12 s12">
    <div class="progress">
      <div class="determinate">
        <i class="fa fa-circle"></i>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```